# What are the different ways of submitting Hadoop jobs?

Tags: command-line-interface, oozie, hadoop2

I just know the below two ways of submitting Hadoop jobs

1) CLI(Command line interface)

2) OOzie

Are there any other ways to do it ? and which is the most widely used method of submitting the Hadoop jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does Hadoop jobs mean ?

MapReduce :  [CLI](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html) + [Oozie](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OOZIE/Map+Reduce+Cookbook)

Spark : [spark-shell + Java / Pyton / Scala](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/programming-guide.html)  + [Spark Job Server (Rest)](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) + [Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SparkActionExtension.html)

Hive : [CLI](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli) + [Java - Thrift(JDBC)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient) + [Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/DG_HiveActionExtension.html)

Pig : [CLI](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/tutorial.html) + [Java](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/PigServer.html) + [Oozie](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OOZIE/Pig+Cookbook)

etc ....... 
If you want to use all of these you can use [Hue](http://gethue.com/).
If you want to schedule all of these you can use Oozie.